# How can I create a function that creates buttons from a text file?

Tags: python, currency

This is a pretty complex question (to me), and I'm not sure if I'm even approaching it correctly. I'm creating a currency converter, and I have a text file with the different currencies and their value in relation to the USD. I've programmed a function that reads the file and stores the name and value in a dictionary. I would like to create a function that creates buttons for each key in the dictionary. Is this possible? This is what I have so far.

```
def cvals():
    global c
    c=open('currencysheet.txt','r')
    global cdict
    cdict={}
    global buttons
    buttons=[]
    for line in c:
        stripped_line=line.strip()
        line_list=stripped_line.split(',')
        line_list1=[str(line_list[0]),float(line_list[1])]
        cdict.update({line_list1[0]: line_list1[1]})
    for i in cdict:
        i=Button1()
    for i in cdict:
        i.name()
        i=Button(sbfr,text=str(i1),command=i.cmd).pack(side=LEFT,fill=X,expand=True)
        print(i1)
```

And the Button1 is a class I created that's not relevant to this question.
If anybody has any questions just let me know!

Comment: Your code is a little confusing - why do you loop through the `cdict` twice - do you have a class called `Button` and another class called `Button1`? Are you just trying to populate the `buttons` list with a bunch of `Button` objects? And while you thikn `Button1` isn't relevant, you are using classes whose definitions are completely unknown to us, so if you want a fitting answer, you will need to provide the definitions so that we can provide (possibly) working code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry about that- I'm new to python and I think a lot of my code is inefficient. The general concept I'm going for is a program that can read a text file, structured like: usd,1
eur,0.98
jpy,136.05
chf,0.96
gbp,0.83
inr,79.83
pkr,228
aud,1.44
cny,6.75
cad,1.29

I want the program to loop through all the lines in the text file and create a button that calls a lambda command with the name (cad, aud, etc.). If I still wasn't too clear just let me know and I'll upload my program. I really appreciate the help!